# Eclipse - Git not showing new files in commit/staging

Tags: java, git, eclipse

I created multiple `java files`  in Eclipse & I notices all new files & even old files amended code are not showing in `git commit` window. I am not sure what is wrong with it.

The last action was that I converted this project to `Maven` & reverted back to `Java Swing application` & some settings were change which I am not aware off!

TIA

Updated Image: ---
[image]

I used `Eclipse` tool for `Git` setup, including staging & for other every action. I did not use `command line git`.

Content of `.gitignore` file: -

[image]

Comment: Is the project already in a git repository's working directory? You've cropped out all of those details.

Comment: According to your screenshot those files are `.gitignore`d.

Comment: yes! it is. It was working before. some settings changed, which I am not aware off.

Comment: why there files are gitignored? It should'nt be1 How can I change this settings

Comment: [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) files are text files that can be edited and by default hidden as they start with `.`.

Comment: how you will tell that the file is `.gitignore`.  How can I add all the files in `git staged` window?

Comment: I linked to the `.gitignore` documentation. `.gitignore`d files cannot be staged for reasons. Please show an uncropped screenshot and all relevant `.gitignore` files (there might be more than one).

Comment: @howlger: - I added the new image, the yellow highlighted are the new files which are not being added to staged window.

Comment: In the _Package Explorere_ view menu (the three dots) choose _Filters..._ and in the filters dialog uncheck _.* resoureces_ to make the `.gitignore` files visible. Add the content of the `.gitignore` files (there might be more than one) to your question. If you used Git also on the command line, in the _Git Staging_ view hit the refresh button.

Comment: All `.gitignore` files, if any, starting from the root directory of the Git repository up to the directory containing the files matter.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with similar issues in the past here is something is which worked for me.

So the first obvious thing you need to look at is .gitignore file which is causing this issue.

A few months ago I was using Eclipse 2020-12 build and it had this weird issue where uncommitted changes were not visible until and unless I update the project and restart the Eclipse manually.

I did a little research on the same but found nothing concrete. So the last resort option was to update the Eclipse version to the latest which indeed fixed the issue.

Hope this helps to you as well.

Comment: I did update the eclipse! It is not valid in my case! I created a new file, still that file does not come up in git -staging.